# Modify the version information of a built .NET assembly

Tags: assemblies, ilasm, ildasm, roundtrip, versioninfo

Is there a better way to modify the version information of a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) assembly of the one I am currently using.

My current approach is the following.

I do disassemble the assembly with *ildasm*:

```
ildasm /nobar Riolo.WebUI.dll /out=Riolo.WebUI.il
```

This will generated also a Riolo.WebUI.res compiled resource file, that I then open and modify with the user interface of Visual Studio, then I do reassemble the assembly back with *ilasm*:

```
ilasm Riolo.WebUI.il /OUTPUT=Riolo.WebUI.dll /RESOURCE=Riolo.WebUI.res /DLL /PDB
```

There are various issues with this process, the main is obviously that I feel like shooting at a mosquito with a broadside of carronades, then that as I don't know how decompile `.res` files to `.rc` files with the command line, I cannot use a command line script, as I have to open Visual Studio to modify the `.res` file, which means it is very time consuming and somewhat error prone, and, last but not least, I do feel that roundtripping assemblies I may well end up loosing information, even if unwittingly, hence I am afraid I will early or later be bitten in some yet unforeseen scenario.

Comment: You could just open the assembly directly without using ildasm.exe, File + Open + File.  Edit the native file version resource.  It is very unclear why you'd have to do this, getting the right stuff into the assembly in the first place is much easier by editing AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: There are various Microsoft tools that generate assemblies without some version info, i.e. **tlbimp.exe** (no company, no copyright, no trademarks and number version always set to 1.0.0.0), or the **Web Deployment projects** (no company, no copyright, no trademarks).

Comment: This bites me in various scenarios, the most obvious being certification for the Windows logo, which requires publisher (company), product name and version number, but also when I have to put together installer for updates (update.exe), as while the interops interface may have changed, their version number has not.

Comment: As I deal with the generation of tens of assemblies, I would love to find a scriptable way to add the missing version info elements as a post build step.