# Can tlbimp.exe generate interop assemblies with customized version info?

Tags: .net, interop, assemblies, tlbimp, versioninfo

The [Microsoft Type Library Importer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx) (tlbimp.exe) generate interop assemblies without some version info, i.e. no company, no copyright, no trademarks and number version always set to 1.0.0.0.
Is it possible to get the tool to generate interop assemblies with customized version info?

This is loosely related with another question I have asked on SO: [Modify the version info of a built .Net assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659818/modify-the-version-info-of-a-built-net-assembly)

Comment: Decompile with ildasm.exe.  Compile with ilasm.exe, using the /resource option to specify a .res file that contains a file version resource that you compiled with rc.exe

Comment: I already knew that ;)
Logan's answer is much more ground breaking!

Comment: I'll leave the comment for users that haven't moved to VS2010 yet.

Comment: Also, it doesn't work if you don't use .Net 4.

Comment: I figured my comment would be useful to *somebody* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You linked to the page that describes how to do so:

```
/asmversion: versionNumber
```

Specifies the version number of the assembly to produce. Specify versionNumber in the format major.minor.build.revision.

```
/product:Product
```

The name of the product with which this assembly
                            is distributed

```
/productversion:Version
```

The version of the product with which this
                            assembly is distributed

```
/company:Company
```

The name of the company that produced this
                            assembly

```
/copyright:Copyright
```

Describes all copyright notices, trademarks, and
                            registered trademarks that apply to this assembly

```
 /trademark:Trademark
```

Describes all trademarks and registered trademarks
                            that apply to this assembly

Comment: Now, that's being found blind to a glaring evidence :)

Comment: As a very partial justification, the page doesn't report the \company, \copyright and \trademark options (it does report \asmversion tough), but then I tried to run tlbimp.exe without parameters, and it correctly reported all the non documented parameters you advised me about! Thank you very much indeed!